# Python save XLSX to CSV

Tags: python, csv

I am not a python user. However, I am sick of saving Excel files to CSV manually, and everybody *hates* Perl at this shop. I can't get `Spreadsheet::XLSX` to work in this work environment. They only use Python.

The python version is 2.4.

```
 #!/usr/bin/python

import openpyxl
import csv

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('DailySnapshot.xlsx')
sh = wb.get_active_sheet()
with open('test.csv', 'wb') as f:
    c = csv.writer(f)
    for r in sh.rows:
        c.writerow([cell.value for cell in r])
```

The `DailySnapshot.xlxs` is saved in the same directory a the script. It is a one page excel spreadsheet, and the sheet is called `'Table1'`. I figured I would name the CSV file test.csv. This is the error it throws.

> File "./secondPyTry.py", line 8
>       with open('test.csv', 'wb') as f:
>               ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Is it really python 2.4?  That's _ancient_, and precedes the introduction of the with syntax.

Comment: Yep, looking now it seems like context managers were introduced in 2.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it was said in the comments, Python 2.4 does not wupport `with`. You should open the file like this instead:

```
f = open('test.csv', 'wb')
c = csv.writer(f)
for r in sh.rows:
    c.writerow([cell.value for cell in r])
f.close()
```